# Integer solutions using PIE

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, inclusion-exclusion

> Find the number of integer solutions to $a+b+c+d=18$ with $ 0≤a,b,c,d≤6$.

With no restrictions there are:

$$\binom{21}{3} = 1330$$

Ones that are invalid are: $a, b, c, d \ge 7$.

But how do I take them out?

Comment: You should add **non negative integers** if you want your `no restrictions` statement to hold.

Comment: @barakmanos, I already considered it in the combination though?

Comment: I don't know about that. You didn't quite bother to explain how you got to this combination, and I'm not sure what PIE means.

Comment: Here's one idea to try if you're really stuck. First consider the case where one of $a, b, c, d$ is $0$. There are $4$ cases, and only one solution in each case: set all the others to exactly $6$. The remaining cases have $a, b, c, d \geq 1$, so the problem reduces to finding $0 \leq a', b', c', d' \leq 5$ so that $a'+ b'+ c'+ d' = 14$. Maybe you can keep going.

Comment: Note that 18/4 > 4 so that the largest of the integers must be 5 or 6. There are not many cases to consider by hand. Then the number of permutations of each must be considered.

Comment: My guess is that PIE is the [Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Setting $p=6-a$, $q=6-b$, $r=6-c$ and $s=6-d$ this comes to the
same as finding the number of integer solutions of:

$$p+q+r+s=6$$

This under the condition that $p,q,r,s$ are firstly nonnegative and secondly
do not exceed $6$.

Fortunately any solution that satisfies the first condition will automatically satisfy the second condition
so we can leave that out, and use the [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) method.

Doing so we find: $$\binom{6+3}{3}=84$$ solutions.

Comment: that's really an amazing trick to solve such problems(which are very recurrent ), and it can be generalized to find the number of integers satisfying $x_1+\cdots+x_p=n$ with each $b_i\leq x_i\leq a_i$

Comment: For slickest ans, +1.

Comment: @Elaqqad: This trick can't always be applied, e.g. it can't be applied for $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = 15,\;$ putting $\;y_i = 6-x_i,\; y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4 = 9$

Comment: How would you solve $a+b+c = 6$ ,$a,b,c \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$ using your method?

Comment: @Abcd In that case this method bears no fruit. We end up with exactly the same problem.

Comment: @drhab Exactly! that's my point. This method won't always work. Could you tell me when will it possibly fail?

Comment: @Abcd It will fail in a general sense. If it works then that is exceptional, but very convenient. It sure is worth to check out when you meet cases like this.

Answer (score 4):

**A different approach:**

$[\text{Number of combinations with sum } K] = [\text{Number of combinations with sum } 24-K]$.

So count the number of combinations with sum $6$ instead of $18$:

- Number of permutations of $6000$ is $\binom41\cdot\binom33=4$
- Number of permutations of $3111$ is $\binom41\cdot\binom33=4$
- Number of permutations of $0222$ is $\binom41\cdot\binom33=4$
- Number of permutations of $3300$ is $\binom42\cdot\binom22=6$
- Number of permutations of $2211$ is $\binom42\cdot\binom22=6$
- Number of permutations of $5100$ is $\binom41\cdot\binom31\cdot\binom22=12$
- Number of permutations of $4200$ is $\binom41\cdot\binom31\cdot\binom22=12$
- Number of permutations of $4110$ is $\binom41\cdot\binom32\cdot\binom11=12$
- Number of permutations of $3210$ is $\binom41\cdot\binom31\cdot\binom21\cdot\binom11=24$

Hence the total number of combinations is $4+4+4+6+6+12+12+12+24=84$.

---

### EDIT:

To be honest, you don't even need the opening statement.

You can simply edit each bullet, and invert each digit $N$ with $6-N$.

Comment: To be honest, you don't even need the opening statement. You can simply take the solution that follows it, and in each bullet, invert each digit $N$ with $6-N$.

Comment: I think it should be $\binom{6+4-1}{4-1}=84$. Seems you forgot $2211$ and its friends.

Comment: @barto: You're right, I did forget $2211$, but its friend ($3300$) was already there. Thank you for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 4):

I know that the OP has most likely the Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion as the method, but just as a check you can use generating functions to verify the answer by barak manos.  Just consider
$$(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^4$$
Since we have 7 numbers to use for each $a,b,c,d$ and 4 variables to choose this will do the trick.  Then just extract the coefficient from the $x^{18}$ term:
$$[x^{18}](1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^4=84$$

Answer (score 2):

Since you specified PIE, here's the solution (though drhab's solution is slicker). Use stars and bars  and apply PIE putting 7 in one or more "bins" so that it exceeds 6.

$${21\choose 3} - {4\choose 1}{14\choose 3} + {4\choose 2}{7\choose 3} = 84$$

Comment: Could you please explain the magic numbers you have used? What do the binomial coefficients represent?

Comment: drhab has given the link to the "stars and bars" formula. See Theorem 2 formula ${n+k-1\choose k-1}$, which yields the initial ${18+4-1\choose 4-1} = {21\choose 3}$. If we now force 7 into a bin to deliberately violate restrictions, which can be done in ${4\choose 1}$ ways, we need to fill 7 less overall, so ${4\choose 1}{14\choose 3}$ and so on applying PIE.

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Comment: @shardulc: You're welcome :)